# Can I save a copy of TeXWorks to a USB drive and download that same copy to a new computer?

Tags: texworks, portability, portable

It is my understanding that I need to download a portable version of TeXLive (my TeX distro) to something like "/TeX Live 2023/" on the USB flashdrive I want to use. But if I want to copy my version of TeXworks, do I need to use a portable version?

The reason I want to copy the version of TeXworks that I have on my computer is that I have a lot of shortcuts that I've written in the resource files and I'd like to be able to use those automatically on any computer which I transfer TeXworks to via the USB.

If there are any clarifying questions, please ask me in the comments.

Comment: In general, no, you can't. TeXworks will be compiled for your OS and will not work on arbitrary other OSs. Depending on what you've installed TeXworks on and how, there may or may not be a discrete thing to copy in the first place. On Linux, for example, TeXworks may not be contained in a single file or directory but is more likely to be distributed in many places. But even if that weren't the case, aren't the changes you've made in your configuration files rather than the application? You may well be able to share those even if you don't share the application.

Comment: Yes good point. I don't have much knowledge on how TeXworks is installed in Windows, but it may be the case that I don't need or want to save the application. Saving a copy of the configuration files will be sufficent and take up less space on the portable drive.

Comment: With actual pendrives sizes, my suggestion is not make a portable texworks  but a  portable OS with texlive and texworks, so you can use in any computer able to boot from USB (almost all computers) no matter they have installed, working always in the same environment. Zero surprises due to computer changes if you save your documents also in the pendrive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Fran. This solution sounds valuable. Could you suggest a resource where I can learn about how to do this?

Comment: @RobinsonWM There are several ways. Depend of what OS you have and what OS you want to install. Usually is get an Image writer tool, download an .iso image with  the SO and buy a pendrive with enough GB to that image, but with Linux you can use even the [dd command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111082/how-to-create-bootable-debian-usb-drive-from-an-existing-linux-partition) in an USB with FAT32 . Linux distros often have installed some tool for this. In Debian there are the packages gnome-multi-writer y mintstick supposedly for this purpose (not tested).